# Omiting parameter in case class apply

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

Sup,
i'm trying to deserialize form data with Play2 but i have encountered a little issue.

code: https://gist.github.com/Hajtosek/a355b800f334a584a547

```
implicit val registerForm = Form(
    mapping(
      "name" -> text,
      "surname" -> text,
      "login" -> text,
      "password" -> text,
      "email" -> text
    )
  )(User.apply)(User.unapply)
  implicit val userFormat = Json.format[User]
}

case class UserLoginData(login: String, password: String)

object User {
  def apply(name: String, surname: String, login: String, password: String, email: String) =
    new User(name, surname, login, password, email, List())
}

case class User(name: String, surname: String, login: String, password: String, email: String, skillSet: List[SkillRecord] = List()) {

}
```

The data i get from the form is (String,String,String, String,String)
but my case class needs (String,String,String, String,String, List[myCustomThing]).

When i hover over the red text in my ide the prompt says not enough arguments for method apply (String,String,String, String,String)

This is register form for my new project, i've tried to override apply in companion object but that didn't work either. I had also tried default values and Option's with similar result.Any suggestions?

Sincerely,

Haito

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ignored function which enables to to define value for the field

```
implicit val registerForm = Form(
    mapping(
      "name" -> text,
      "surname" -> text,
      "login" -> text,
      "password" -> text,
      "email" -> text,
      "skillSet" -> ignored(List.empty[SkillRecord])
    )
  )(User.apply)(User.unapply)
```

Comment: I ended up writing custom apply and unapply but your answer is far Moore convenient